# How to crawl 5000 different URLs to find certain links

Tags: python, web-scraping, async-await, web-crawler

I have a list of URLs which has about 5k urls, I want to crawl each of these websites and find links to certain other page, which most these websites have.
To solve this issue i wrote a python script which works but its too slow. I was hoping to find a better solution than mine.

The below code takes about 2 mins to complete for just 10 links. Is there any way to make it more faster or some other method altogether.

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin

timeout = 5
async def fetch_html(session, url):
    async with session.get(url, headers=headers, timeout=timeout) as response:
        return await response.text()

async def find_info_page(session, start_url, max_depth=2):
    visited_urls = set()
    queue = [(start_url, 0)]
    ans_list = []
    while queue:
        current_url, depth = queue.pop(0)
        if current_url in visited_urls or depth > max_depth:
            continue

        visited_urls.add(current_url)

        try:
            html = await fetch_html(session, current_url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
            for link in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
                absolute_link = urljoin(current_url, link['href'])
                if pattern.search(absolute_link.lower()):
                    ans_list.append(absolute_link)
                    return absolute_link
                elif absolute_link != current_url:
                    queue.append((absolute_link, depth + 1))
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing {current_url}: {e}")
            
    return None

async def main():
    start_urls = links[:10]

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = [find_fee_page(session, url) for url in start_urls]
        results = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


    for url, result in zip(start_urls, results):
        if result:
            print(f"Fee page found for {url}: {result}")
        else:
            print(f"No fee page found for {url}")

await main()
```

short explanation of the code

fetch_html() : this function is an async co-routine and all it does it makes a request to the given url asynchronously.

find_info_page(): this function is also an async co-routine,

- it crawls the given url page, for that it calls the fetch-html function to get the html source of the given url.
- then it gets all the links ( tags) on the page, check for a certain condition on the link, if not found then it crawls the newly found links until it find the info its looking.

main() : it's just a wrapper function to create a shared session object and for using asyncio.gather() function, which ensures async functionality.

Comment: Try the threading library? It sounds as if you've done the `async` stuff wrong somewhere, but I've not used it before so couldn't point you to where.

Comment: Putting multi-processing aside, how long does it take to fetch one url via the requests package? If you can get 10 a second is that fast enough to simplify things without using multiprocessing/async/threads?

Comment: How many actual HTTP requests did your code do in those two minutes?